# Objective-C - How to put black transparent on image in

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode6

I would like to add black transparent at the bottom of an Image some thing like shown in below image.[image]

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but try to be more specific with your questions. Instead of saying "Thanks in advance for your suggestions" ask "how can I go about doing this?". . and explain the depth of your current understanding, such as what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do such dark gradient. The easiest one is to use a `CAGradientLayer` like so

```
// Create a gradient layer
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
// gradient from transparent to black
layer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
// set frame to whatever values you like (not hard coded like here of course)
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 200.0);
// add the gradient layer as a sublayer of you image view
[imageView.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Another option is to generate a stretchable `UIImage` and use it in a `UIImageView` which is added as a subview to the original `UIImageView`, like so:

```
CGFloat gradientHeight = 200.0f; // set to whatever height you want your gradient to be
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(1.0f, gradientHeight); // image will be stretched so can be 1pt wide

// prepare image with gradient
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// gradient from transparent to black
NSArray *colors = @[(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), (CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointZero, CGPointMake(0.0f, imageSize.height), kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);

// get image from the context
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// create image view with the gradient image
UIImageView *gradientImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

// set frame height to same value as imageHeight, and width to fill the superview (ignore this hard-coded 320)
gradientImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, gradientHeight);
// add the gradient image view as a subview to the image view
[imageView addSubview:gradientImageView];
```

Both options will give you a result like this:
[image]

Comment: I've tried the both options and they are working well in normal View Controller. But if i use table View cell(each cell has imageview) and when i scroll the tableview the gradient layer is increasing towards the top of an image and then complete image is displaying in black color.

Comment: @Javeed you are probaby creating and adding it again whenever the cell is reused (if I understand correctly). You should add the gradient to the cell only once when it is created, and only adjust its frame when reusing the cell.

Comment: you are correct. I was using the above snippets in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method. Now i've placed the code in Custom cell "awakeFromNib" method and it's working as i required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom view.

- Start by adding the image view content.
- Add a semi-transparent container for the text.
- Add the labels to the semi-transparent container.
- Implement layoutSubviews for placement.

Implementation would look something like:

```
@implementation MyCustomView
{
    UIImageView _imageView;
    UIView _labelConainer;
} 

//If this is a table view use initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier instead
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [self setupImageView];
    [self setupLabels];
}

- (void)layouSubViews {
    [_imageView setFrame:self.bounds];
    [_labelContainer setFrame:CGRectMake(
        0, self.frame.size.height - 50, self.frame.size.width, 50)
    //Layout labels in semi-transparent container, relative to parent. 
}


- (void)setupImageView {
    _imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:anImage];
    //For table views instead use self.contentView
    [self addSubview:_iamgeView];
 }


- (void)setupLabelContainer {
    _labelContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [_labelContainer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [_labelContainer setAlpha:0.7];
    [self addSubview:_labelContainer];

    //Add some labels to label container
 }
```

You could also set this up in a XIB and use auto-layout.